# How to get first elements from a pyspark array?

Tags: pyspark

I have an array and I just keep a specific column from it like this in PySpark:

c = [ "green", "blue", "red", "yellow",... ]

And I want to keep the n first elements of this column
How can I do this please ? I know is a simple question but I don't find the solution ...

Thanks

Comment: pyspark does not have lists, it has array type field. python has lists. could you share more details on how you're using the aforementioned?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, 

Ok so I have an array with some columns

Then I juste keep the color column using : 
c = myArray.color

And the shape of c is like this : [ "green", "blue", "red", "yellow",... ]

But I want to keep first n elements 

Thanks !

Comment: is `c` a dataframe? could you please the details in the question itself?

Comment: It's an array, I will provide this detail in the question

Comment: what is `myArray` and how was it created? what is the type of `myArray` and `c` (what does `type(c)` output)? a pyspark array is useless outside a pyspark dataframe.

Comment: I find the solution, I used this : c2 = c.slice(0,n)
I will check what is the type

Comment: isn't that a java method? are you using spark on java